# Removing characters from text file in Linux

Tags: sed

I've just joined SO after watching from the outside for just over a year now. The reason I've finally joined is because I could do with some help :)

I have a text file with a list of email addresses. The email addresses are in the following format:

```
<firstinitial><surname>@domain.com
```

I'd like to edit the text file so the output gives me:

```
<firstinitial><first3lettersofsurname>@domain.com
```

I've tried using sed, but can seem to get this one. Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Phill.

Comment: `tried using sed` please add that code to question.. as you've used SO before, you'd have seen questions adding code attempted by OP :)

Comment: and please add exact input/output sample without any modification.. for ex: it is not clear if you want to change `surname` to `first3lettersofsurname` or change `foobar` to `foo`

Comment: Thanks for the pointers Sundeep :)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/(....).*(@.*)/\1\2/' file
```

---

> `.`: matches a single character. Does not matter what character it is, except newline
>
> `*`: matches preceding match zero or more times
>
> `\1`: repeat the first capturing group `(....)`in the matched expression
>
> `\2`: repeat the second capturing group `(@.*)`in the matched expression

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Thank you Cyrus, this is awesome! :D

Would you please be as kind to explain the syntax? It's worked a treat, but I'd like to understand exactly how it's worked.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain Cyrus, it's most appreciated.